# How does the SpellingCorrectionList function work? (with confusing example)

Tags: text, linguistics

I tried the SpellingCorrectionList function on some chunks of code strings to get translation suggestions. The results are kind of wild. I understand guesses are not going to be great on a string of nonsense, but for example I had a couple strings like "BULTG" and "BULTIE". In my results I got "BULGY", "BULGE", and "BULLETIN" but I did not get "BULLET" or "BUILT" which I think are a lot closer to these argument strings. Any explanation for why this would happen?

Comment: I did `SpellingCorrectionList["BULTIE"]` and I got `{"BULLETIN", "BULLET", "BULTMANN", "BUILDER"}`. When I did `SpellingCorrectionList["BULTG"]` I got `{"BULGY", "BULLDOG", "BALTIC"}`. Both lists seem reasonable to me but it's a shame there isn't a method to get more alternatives. I have Mathematica 12.1.1.0 on Windows 10. Perhaps you are using an older version ?

Comment: In fact, you could try `nf = Nearest[DictionaryLookup[__]]; nf[ToLowerCase@"BULTG"]` - yields `{"belt", "belts", "blag", "bolt", "bolts", "bug", "built", "bulb", \
"bulbs", "bulge", "bulgy", "bulk", "bulks", "bulky", "bull", "bulls", \
"bully", "bung", "bunt", "bunts", "burg", "bust", "busts", "busty", \
"but", "buts", "butt", "butte", "butts", "butty", "cult", "cults", \
"gulag"}` and `nf[ToLowerCase@"BULTIE"]` gets me `{"auntie", "belie", "budgie", "bulge", "bulgier", "bulkier", \
"bullied", "bullier", "bullies", "bustier", "bustle", "butte", \
"butties", "cutie", "Julie", "untie"}`